Were Yom Kippur korbanos eaten on Yom Kippur
I know that some korbanos such as a chatos would be eaten by the kohanim  , what about the korbanos chatos of Yom Kippur did they wait until after Yom Kippur to eat it or did they actually eat it on Yom Kippur or where they not eaten at all?

The meat was eaten at night after the fast. If the next day was Shabbat they'd have eat it raw since you can't cook on Shabbat or Yom Kippur. If Yom Kippur was on Shabbat, the shewbread would be distributed only at night after the fast. (Mishna Menachot 11:7)

Specifically the Alexandrian kohanim ate the se'ir because they were not generally repulsed from eating raw meat (Menachos 100a).
